# Extending user model with different profiles

Tags: django, django-users

I have an application where the amount of users logging in to system will be not more than 10 or 15. I have two type of users - a frontdesk user and a doctor type. Both of them have some common fields and some unique ones. For e.g a doctor might have a field like cardio or pediatrician, etc. The django recommended way of extending user model, does authenticate one type of users only I think. Would making a Doctor model with a OneToOneField be an accepted way to implement this?

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    #doctor specific fields
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class FrontDesk(models.Model):
    #frontdesk specific fields
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

And for frontdesk the same way?

I am using django 1.5. Django user model also uses username for returning value in the `__unicode__` function. I want the user to be able to see the name of the doctor. So the built-in functionality isn't OK for me. What would you suggest?

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: I am asking if this way is going to be efficient is it a suggested way for doing this?It will work like this..But is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there will be any problem with what you are doing.

You can define the unicode function to return the username of doctor or frontdesk user in this way:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Comment: That's what i wanted to know..Thank you. I want first_name and last_name so its return (%s %s) %(self.first_name, self.last_name). Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

why not combine them with abstract:

```
class CommonCustomer(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #all common fields
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Doctor(CommonCustomer):
    #doctor specific fields
    docid = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class FrontDesk(CommonCustomer):
    #frontdesk specific fields
    fdid = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

Comment: Then how do I register a Doctor? Do I use the UserRegister generic form?